# Custom 404 error page with Japanese become unreadable on Tomcat 5, only when access from a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I have troubled with custom error page on Tomcat 5.0.28. Error page written in Japanese become unreadable. (likes ... あいう -> ??????)

My environment.

- Java Sun SDK 1.4
- Tomcat 5.0.28

I have a Java application what has a servlet to convert extension from .htm to .jsp of any URL request. My JSPs written in Japanese, so requires encoding specified content-Type header, and the servlet provides it. They get along well.

I want to add a customized Japanese 404 error page to this app. But that 404 page's Japanese become unreadable only when access via the servlet. It looks like lose a encoding specified Content-Type header that case(I see a HTTP request header on that page). Normally `text/html; charset=Shift_JIS`, but when unreadable becomes `text/html`.

Not through that servlet, Content-Type header is as usual and customized 404 page's Japanese are works. The servlet is only mapped to request that have extension *.htm .

My error page settings on application's web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

My servlet source:

```
public class Converter extends HttpServlet {
    public void init() throws ServletException {
    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=Shift_JIS");
        ServletContext context = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String reqUrl = request.getServletPath();

        String jspName = reqUrl.substring(1,reqUrl.indexOf("."));
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/"+jspName+".jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

error page JSP "404.jsp":

```
<%@ page language="java" isErrorPage="true" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS" pageEncoding="Shift_JIS" %>
<html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">
     </head>
     <body>
     test 404<br />
     日本語出力テスト<br />
     </body>
</html>
```

Request URL and output (no such JSP/HTM files on server):

`http://example.com/nonexisting.htm`(through the servlet)

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">
    </head>
    <body>
    test 404<br />
    ????????<br />
    </body>
</html>
```

`http://example.com/nonexisting.jsp`(not through the servlet)

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">
    </head>
    <body>
    test 404<br />
    日本語出力テスト<br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's some tests I tried. Each files are written in Shift_JIS and contains Japanese.

Existing file request tests.

- mydomain.com/existing.jsp(not through the servlet) -> no problem.
- mydomain.com/existing.htm(through the servlet) -> no problem.

Non-existing file request tests(Sure, no such files on my server.).

- mydomain.com/nonexisting.jsp(not through the servlet) -> displays custom 404 page with Japanese, and no problem.
- mydomain.com/nonexisting.htm(through the servlet) -> displays custom 404 page, but loses Content-Type header and Japanese characters are unreadable.

Additionally I tried:

- I tried CharacterEncodingFilter bundled with Tomcat, but it also doesn't work. Configure as to make a request encoded as Shift_JIS when it's /404.jsp, but results same as above.

Thanks for to be patient my terrible English (>_<)
Any help would be very appreciated.

---

## Solved

Just remove never used getWriter(), then the 404 page no more lacks encoding-specified Content-Type header and works.

```
public class Converter extends HttpServlet {
    public void init() throws ServletException {
    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=Shift_JIS");
        ServletContext context = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
        //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String reqUrl = request.getServletPath();

        String jspName = reqUrl.substring(1,reqUrl.indexOf("."));
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/"+jspName+".jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code example is blatantly incomplete: out and reqUrl aren't used, and you don't write the response.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I append some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two general error classes:

- the 404 response has a **Content-Type** header stating it is **charset=Shift_JIS** but it actually is encoded differently or corrupted. Assuming *404.jsp* is encoded correctly on disk, it could be corrupted when it's loaded into a string or converted when the string is written to the HTTP response. Where do you set the encoding of your Reader and/or Writers to Shift_JIS?
- the 404 response is encoded as Shift_JIS but the Content-Type header specifies a different **charset** (or none, defaulting to ISO-8859-1). Your **doGet()** method *appears* to do the right thing for 200 responses, but 404 errors are likely to take a different path.

Clearly, looking at the HTTP headers of your 404 response would be very informative. You should also debug the application to inspect how 404 responses are handled.

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo. I got it by some of you point ... Just remove unused `getWriter()` is works. At regular case encoding works correctly, and 404.jsp is encoded by Shift_JIS. But 404.jsp's HTTP-header, Content-Type is "text/html"(maybe default) as you said. It should be getWriter() outputs responce object and purge it. So responce doesn't retain setContentType() for later request. 
Anyway, thanks a lot!